# Cannot install Firebird on XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, firebird

I have windows 2003 server and XAMPP running on it. Now I can't configure PHP to connect to Firebird server. I cannot install firebird support on php. I have uncommented

```
extension=php_interbase.dll
```

and

```
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

and I have downloaded gds32.dll from here
http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?gds32

and put it in C:\Windows folder. But it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the full Firebird server and client , gds32.dll is a legacy dll

http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-2-upd1/

also you can try to copy fbclient.dll from  Firebird/bin folder to c:\xampp\apache\bin

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working.